# wordpress query similar meta_key withen userid

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress for my site.
I store some data in wp_usermeta per user now i wanna query users similarity by their wp_usermeta keys.

Here is wordpress wp_usermeta scheme

```
umeta_id
userid
meta_key
meta_value
```

i need to query `userid = 1 and userid = 2 where userid_1.meta_key = userid_2.meta_key`

no need for meta_value check just `userid_1.meta_key = userid_2.meta_key`

Comment: can you please provide sample data !

Comment: not getting what you exactly want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$users = get_users(array(
    'meta_key'     => 'meta_key',
    'include'      => array(1,2),
));
print_r($users);
print_r(count($users));
?>
```

if

1. both have same meta_key then first print array of two object and second print `2`.
2. not have same key then first print `array()` and second print `0`